# Magento refresh cache on plugin save

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have written a simple Magento plugin that simply lists all sub categories that are enabled from a given parent id.

The user simply selects a parent category id from the admin using the plugin tab i have created.

To speed things up i have added block caching to the plugin using the following code

```
 $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime' => 86400,
            'cache_tags' => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG)
        ));
```

This works well so far, as if a sub category is enabled / disabled the cache invalidates and is replaced. However if i change the parent category id in the admin changes are not seen until the whole block cache is refreshed using system->cache managment.

What i would like to do is have a method where by when a user clicks save in the admin the cache is flushed for just this one block rather than refreshing everything.

How would i go about this ? i am thinking some sort of event observer on the save event in adminhtml?  however i wouldn't know how to do this.

I am interested on what thoughs / suggestions other people may have.

Many thanks

Ian Cassidy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an Event Observer to clean cache. You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) to setup your observers, and then observe the `catalog_category_save_after` event.

To clear cache, use `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG);` in your Observer Model.

PS: maybe you have to setup your `<events>` into `<admin>` or `<adminhtml>` instead of `<globals>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use observer generate when click refresh action in cache management. after that , you can clear cache by cache tag or cache Id . This is solution to clearn cache by cache id. can you see [how to refresh cache in custom cache type](http://www.worldofcoder.com/2013/11/create-new-cache-type-in-magento.html)