# How can I save all order place data in custom table along with Magento default tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento, customization

In Magento, once Customer places Order, that data automatically goes to Sales_flat_order table or for item related information goes to sales_flat_order_item table etc.
 Likewise I have selected some columns in Magento database & created 1 custom table in Magento database.
 Now My requirement is, once customer places Order that data also must get copied to custom table along with Magento\’s default table.

So for that I created one mysql query through joins that will fetch all my needed data from Magento tables & insert it in my Custom table....
 Now I am planning to create php file that includes my above query.

My doubt is how & where should I change My Magento code so that once customer places order, I will call to this file so that I can copy data in custom table through that query.
 I get some reference as When customer places order, it will use saveOrder function in Onepage model which is at Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php

So can anybody tell me what exactly I need to do in this scenario....Anyone having such scenario or sample code for the same…
 Or having any other idea…

Plz guide me…

Thanks..

Comment: Why are you duplicating stored data? There are order save events which ca be observed, but you need a fairly strong argument to duplicate storage.

Comment: Hi Ben, I am duplicating stored data as I want to migrate data from custom table into oracle...as I have connected Mysql & ORACLE DATABASE THROUGH php...can you please explain me about order save events...

Comment: Hi Sonassi, Can you please explain how can I use MYSQL views in such situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow my tip on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588547/magento-refresh-cache-on-plugin-save/9657654#9657654) but observing the `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` event.

Comment: I would catch sales_order_save_after

Comment: Hi Rafael, your blog is very informative & useful. I have created one custom table which contains Magento sales order column. I have creaated one query through Joins which fetches data from Magento tables & inserts it into custom table. I have connected MySql & Oracle through PHP & I have put that query in this php file.Now I wanted to  place an event after order is placed in Magento so that this event call my query file which results in insertion of data in custom table....If u have any sample code for the same plz provide that...or plz guide me...

Comment: I'd better to create an external service to do that. I think punish your customer with a extra time to commit in both DBMS is not a good option. You can use Magento API to do that. http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento_core_api

Comment: Hi Rafael,Can u plz explain more how we can use Magento API methods in such scenario? how to create external services?
How to include external PHP file in magento.as I already mentioned, My php files contain connection to mysql & oracle databases & query which fetches & inserts data into databases.
Nw wht I am thinking is If I got order-Id from event-observer method...then can I put that php file code in this Observer.php so that with thr generated order-id, data can be fetched & inserted in Custom table?Or how Can I include/execute that PHP file from my event-observer model??
Plz guide me.

Comment: Create an external service (e.g.: PHP called by cron) that connects to your Magento API and do the job, according with the link in my comment above. Otherwise, you can use Magento including Magento Core and work with models.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a MySQL Trigger?

```
# target table name target_table
# source table name Sales_flat_order table

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ON_INSERT_AFTER_SALES
AFTER INSERT ON Sales_flat_order
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO target_table VALUES(field_one,field_two,...);
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Can I include/execute external PHP file using event-observer method? How to do that?

Comment: dear friend, if your aim to make mirroring one of the table, the best idea is trigger. Above code snippet, backup whole new rows of the source table into target table. You can make delet syntax as well. I didn't understand your reason about event observer!

Comment: Hi Oguz, I am using event-observer so that after customer press PLACE ORDER tab i.e. at the time of order creation, order id must get passed to my php file containing query. so that required data get fetch & insert into custom tables.

Comment: Therefore, just use MySQL trigger for insert and delete. This is the best idea for you. You do not need to take an order id to insert record to another table. Trigger will do everything without hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento's **sales_order_place_after** event, create an observer for this and put you code into it.